# How to add a firestore document and await for completion on swift using Codable

Tags: swift, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, task, codable

I'm trying to figure out how to await for a .addDocument(from:) when adding documents to firestore, since the current FirebaseFirestoreSwift library doesn't have an async method for that, I am trying to do so with a listener

This is my code

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class UserService {
    
    let firestore = Firestore.firestore()
  
    func createUserAwaiting(user: User) async throws -> DocumentReference {
        let ref = try firestore.collection("users").addDocument(from: user)
        var listener: ListenerRegistration
        let ta =  Task { () async -> DocumentReference in
            listener = ref.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                    if querySnapshot.exists {
                        listener.remove()
                        ta.value = ref //this line is obviously not working
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return await ta.value
     }
    
}
```

I hope the main idea of what I want to do is clear, basically I want a function that adds a document using Codable user, and awaits for the addition to be completed returning the document reference generated

Comment: I find combine working better for listeners when I want to receive a streamline of values from Firestore, otherwise like getDocuments and getDocument I use aswync/await.